# JSON World City list

Tags: json, autocomplete

What is the best service out there to popluate and Auto complete city list ? I tried to use http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html but the amount of daily request is too low for my needs and it seems that the premium account cost 60 USD a month which is way other my budget.

Would anyone know of a good alternative for that service ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best autocomplete city list service I've found is the one from Geobytes : http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api.htm

You can perform up to 50,000 requests per day for free. Is that enough for your needs ?